# ID column does not work with concatenate formula in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to create simple unique ID for my SharePoint List.

All I need to say is ABC-001, ABC-002 ETC. I am using formula `=concatenate("ABC-", ID)`.

It works if I refresh the formula every time. But when ever I change some thing in the LIST this shows as **ABC-0**.

It takes out the ID number such as 1, 2, 3. help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with using `ID` in calculated formula.

**Workaround**:

Instead of using calculated column, you can run a power automate flow on item creation/update to update list item with required details.

1. Create a single line of text column in list
2. Hide it from list forms
3. Create a power automate flow with trigger **When an item is created or modified**.
4. Set the text column using **Update item** action

**Documentation**: [Microsoft SharePoint Connector in Power Automate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers)

Comment: Hi, I Do not have the option to use power automate or SharePoint design. Is there any other way?

Comment: You can use SharePoint designer 2013 workflow as well to achieve this.

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps to do this:

1. Create a Calculated Field called ID2 (or whatever).  Set the value to [ID].  Make sure the type is set to Text.  This converts the ID to Text.
2. Create 2nd Calculated field.  Set the Value to:  =concatenate("ABC-", ID2).

Note: This works in SharePoint Online.  I have not tested in other versions of SharePoint.